# Как я могу пройти по всем файлам в папке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

Есть заданный путь, допустим, диск D:, как я могу пройти по всем папкам и подпапкам, доходя до файлов?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь стандартным модулем [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path("D:/")
for x in p.rglob("*"):
    print(x)
```

Comment: Так ведь таким образом оно не проходит по подпапкам, а на выходе файлы в исходной папке + подпапки

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, так мы рекурсивно проходим по всему дереву, начиная с указанного пути, и печатаем все директории и файлы. Вы пробовали запустить этот код?

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритмы обхода дерева в универе учили? Вот и примените его на практике. Это он и есть, в чистом виде. Надеюсь, как просмотреть все файлы в одном каталоге вы знаете (по крайней мере - этого вы не спрашивали). Подсказки: 1) в самом каталоге всегда есть два специальных файла, с именами "." и ".." указывающими на сам каталог и на его родителя (для облегчения обхода дерева). 2) Каталог -  есть специальный вид файла.